# Allow ftp user to read and write his home, except some subfolders

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have vsftp installed on my webserver and I need to "jail" a specific account (say "newdev") to a folder (/var/www/[site.com]) so that account cannot read or write outside of that folder.

This is pretty usual and I found tons of guides, **but** I wonder if there is some sort of configuration that let me exclude some subfolders.

Let's assume this structure:

```
root
+-- etc
+-- lib
+-- var
    +-- www
        +-- site.com        # "newdev" account "jailed" here with r/w rights
            +-- js          # inherit rights
            +-- css         # inherit rights
            +-- modules     <-- I want to exclude this
            +-- index.php   # inherit rights
```

Is there some setting that, once the "newdev" account login, sees "/var/www/site.com" as its home, and can read and write every subfolder, except the "modules" one?

(*moved here from stackoverflow since off-topic there*)

Comment: Normal permissions aren't sufficient?

Comment: If the user is still able to change perms, use `chattr +i` on the folder you want immutable with the understanding this will cause confusion down the road when debugging and may annoy some admins.

Comment: @MichaelHampton should I chmod the "modules" folder to prevent user writing? There could be problems with the group www-data which now owns it?

Comment: @Aaron will this setting prevent me (root) from editing that folder?

Comment: @MattiaGalati The setting would make the folder read-only.  To modify things requires removing it then putting it back.

Comment: @Aaron unfortunately this solution doesn't fit for me: other senior devs should be able to write to that folder at will.

Comment: In that case you would need to enable acl's on that partition.  acl's can get really complicated, really fast, especially in chroot sftp, but you can set more granular permissions.